# dired alternative to openwith: how to open file per extension?

Tags: dired, openwith

`openwith` seems to kill replying in `mu4e`.

Is there a similar/alternative solution for easy defining default apps per extensions in `dired`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say that "`openwith` seems to kill replying in `mu4e`"?  I use both and have no problem with them.  Does this problem persist if you start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`)?

Comment: Hi Dan. when i hit 'R' the reply dosent launch and i get this error: error in process filter: Opening input file. any clue?

Comment: Try `(add-to-list 'mm-inhibit-file-name-handlers 'openwith-file-handler)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that [dired-launch](https://github.com/thomp/dired-launch) is of some value. I developed it as a launcher specifically for [dired-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredMode) (unlike `openwith`... which tries to work in a variety of settings). `dired-launch` provides a keybinding (`J`) which allows one to launch the default external application corresponding to that file.

Answer (score 5):

On Debian, this is how I do it:

```el
(defun mu-open-in-external-app ()
  "Open the file where point is or the marked files in Dired in external
app. The app is chosen from your OS's preference."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((file-list
          (dired-get-marked-files)))
    (mapc
     (lambda (file-path)
       (let ((process-connection-type nil))
         (start-process "" nil "xdg-open" file-path))) file-list)))
```

And then I have this:

```el
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-<return>") #'mu-open-in-external-app)
```

You can bind `RET` instead.

```el
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "RET") #'mu-open-in-external-app)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, vanilla Dired has help for this, and [**Dired+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) provides some more help.

1. You can use `!` on a file (or marked files) to run a shell program on it. Use `M-n` to cycle among possible commands.  These commands to choose from come from the MIME type of the file (see non-option variable `mailcap-mime-data`).  They can also come from entries that you make in user option **`dired-guess-shell-alist-user`** (you will need to load standard library `dired-x.el` for this).
2. If you use Emacs on MS Windows and you have both **Dired+** and library [**`w32-browser.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/w32-browser.el) (see [Ms Shell Execute](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsShellExecute)) then you can use `M-RET` in Dired to open a file or directory using its Windows file association (i.e., its "open" program).

Comment: thx Drew! i use linux (arch linux). I have been using ! with the dired-x and it works great but what i really want is to press ENTER and launch the app (im lazy i guess). openwith works great in that sense. best, Z

Comment: Then bind a key that does that: invokes the app. Usually the question is *which app*? That's what `dired-guess-default` is about. It is used by `dired-guess-shell-command` which is used by via `M-n` (`dired-read-shell-command`) from `!` (`dired-do-shell-command`). It just looks through `dired-guess-shell-alist-user and `dired-guess-shell-alist-default` for a match for your filename, to get the app. If you know the shell command you want for a given file, then do `(dired-do-shell-command THE-SHELL-COMMAND current-prefix-arg THE-FILES-TO-ACT-ON)` in the Emacs command you bind to a key.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand on Manuel Uberti's answer.

I use EWXM, and I don't want to accidentally open another Emacs instance. Before running `xdg-open`, I first run `xdg-mime` a couple of times to check whether the application that will open the file is Emacs. If it is, skip the current file.

I'm new to Elisp, and I appreciate suggestions for improvement!

```
;;;###autoload
(defun my/open-in-external-app ()
  "Open the file where point is or the marked files in Dired in external
app. The app is chosen from your OS's preference."
  (interactive)
  (mapc
   (lambda (file-path)
     (let* ((mime-type (string-trim (shell-command-to-string (concat "xdg-mime query filetype '" file-path "'"))))
            (default-application (string-trim (shell-command-to-string (concat "xdg-mime query default " mime-type)))))
       (unless (equal default-application "emacs.desktop")
         (let ((process-connection-type nil))
           (start-process "" nil "xdg-open" file-path)))))
   (dired-get-marked-files)))
```

One more thing: When I attempted to load the `define-key` sexp on startup, I got an error about `dired-mode-map` being unbound. So I wrapped it with `with-eval-after-load`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'dired
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-<return>") #'my/open-in-external-app))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try package [`dired-open`](https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#dired-open)

[Here's the entry into my `.emacs`](https://github.com/bvraghav/dotemacs/blob/master/setup/dired-setup.el#L96-L102)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25711)